# Change Color of Icon in React

Tags: javascript, css, html, reactjs

I have a one React component which contains iteration of div elements like below:

```
render(){
  return(
      <div className="col-md-12">
         {this.state.pageOfItems.map(opration =>
                <div className=" col-md-4 icondiv" key={opration.id}
                    onClick={this.selectOperation.bind(this,opration,true)}> 
                  <FontAwesome name="square"  style={{ ariaHidden:true, fontSize:'35px'}}/>
                       <span className="displayblock">{opration.name}</span>
                 </div>

          )}
      </div>
    );
}
```

Now my question is When I my onClick method execute I want to change clicked div's square icon color. remaining icon's color should be same. Now when I clicked on another div's icon then same should happen. How can I achieve this. I know I can set css color to different but How can I identified particular div and change color?

Comment: consider accepting the working answer! https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer.. you gain 2 rep points every time you accept an answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your state, add a member 'selectedOperationId' and update it in the 'selectOperation' callback.

Then build the className of your div conditionnaly like

```
className={operation.id === this.state.selectedOperationId ? "selected col-md-4 icondiv" : "col-md-4 icondiv"}
```

and make the proper css for .selected class

Comment: @realcodes Glad it worked, you should mark this answer as the accepted answer so others with the same problem can quickly know that this is helpful.